# In which intervals does OneNote saves my notebook?

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010

How much time elapsed between one save to another?

In my area there are a lot of electricity power interruption, so I don't know how much I can count on OneNote autosaving.

Comment: I'd be more concerned about whether it saves in place, or makes a second copy and replaces the first only after the second save is completely written to disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set [at which intervals the notebooks are backed up](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/onenote-help/backup-and-restore-your-notes-HA010211723.aspx), if that helps surviving the power interrupts.

Answer (score 3):

It won't matter.  ON saves your changes to a local cache every few milliseconds, and then sends changes from the cache to the notebook on the server every few minutes.  If that process is interrupted, ON will notice the server notebook does not have the changes in the cache and will re-sync when you start OneNote again.